# What is causing this PHP warning for the mysqli_poll function?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, asyncsocket, mysqlnd

I'm using the MySQL native driver for PHP to make asynchronous, parallel queries from a PHP application to a MySQL DB.

I have a function that receives an array of query strings and executes them in parallel.

For whatever reason though, in one particular environment where I'm using this function, the following PHP warning is being output to the Apache `error_log` en masse:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_poll(): Parameter 1 not a mysqli object
```

My assumption is that this occurs when one or more of the DB connection variables passed in the array for the first argument of the [`mysqli_poll`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.poll.php) function is not a valid MySQLi object, but looking at my code, I don't understand how it could ever reach this point to begin with.

Specifically, here's the code in question:

```
function makeAsyncQueries($queries) {

  $allLinks = [];
  $allLinkThreadIds = [];
  $allResults = [];

  foreach ($queries as $query) {

    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query, MYSQLI_ASYNC);

    if ($result !== false) {
      $allLinks[] = $link;
      $allLinkThreadIds[] = mysqli_thread_id($link);
    } else {
      // Attempting to log. This condition is never met.
    }

  }

  $processed = 0;

  while ($processed < count($allLinks)) {

    $links = $errors = $reject = [];

    foreach ($allLinks as $link) {
      $links[] = $errors[] = $reject[] = $link;
    }

    if (mysqli_poll($links, $errors, $reject, 0, 0)) { // This causes the error.

      foreach ($links as $link) {

        if ($results = mysqli_reap_async_query($link)) {

          $idx = array_search(mysqli_thread_id($link), $allLinkThreadIds);

          if ($results !== false) {
            $allResults[$idx] = processDbResults($results); // Custom function
          } else {
            // Attempting to log. This condition is never met.
          }

          freeResults($link); // Custom function
          $processed++;

        }

      }

    }

  }

  ksort($allResults);
  return $allResults;

}
```

If for some reason the result of `mysqli_query` is invalid, then the `$result` variable should be `false`, right? But the else part of `if ($result !== false)` never gets satisfied, so is it safe to make the assumption that `$result` is valid and that `$link` is a valid MySQLi object?

If that's the case though, then how can I ever get the PHP warning from the `mysqli_poll` function call?

Any pointers to help guide me in where I'm misunderstanding something would be extremely helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Took a while to figure out, but it turns out that the MySQL DB was actually intermittently going out to lunch, which was causing this problem. Once we resolved the DB issues, this problem went away.